# what happens to old values of std::vector, when I do std::vector = std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have following code snippet:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1;
v1.push_back("Hello");
v1.push_back("World");

std::vector<std::string> v2;
v2.push_back("Good");
v2.push_back("Bye");

v1 = v2;
```

What will happen to the old values of vector `v1`.

- Old values will be destructed immediately?

or

- They will destroy when vector `v1` destroys. Then How can I free them immediately?

Answer (score 7):

According [to](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) [the](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) [references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673471.aspx)

> Any elements held in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed.

So, in your example, the original underlying `std::string` values will have the `std::string::operator=` called on them and they (the underlying `std::string` itself) will not be destroyed.

If the vector being assigned *to* is larger than the vector being assigned *from*, then you would have the destructor called for the elements in the vector, example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1;
v1.push_back("Hello");
v1.push_back("There");
v1.push_back("World");

std::vector<std::string> v2;
v2.push_back("Good");
v2.push_back("Bye");

v1 = v2;
```

In this example, the `std::string` values for `"Hello"` and `"There"` will be assigned `"Good"` and `"Bye"` respectively while the 3rd string of `"World"` will be destroyed.

Remember though this applies **only** to the element contained in the vector, take the following code for example:

```
std::vector<int*> v1;
v1.push_back(new int(42));
v1.push_back(new int(24));
v1.push_back(new int(38));

std::vector<int*> v2;
v2.push_back(new int(32));
v2.push_back(new int(23));

v1 = v2;
```

In this code, a memory leak occurs since `v1` is a vector containing pointers, the pointers themselves are assigned/destroyed, not the value it points to. This example is equivalent to the following:

```
int* x = new int(42);
int* y = new int(24);
x = y; // memory leak here
```

To this, if you wish to remove the elements from the vector (thus calling the destructor of each element in the container), you can use the [`clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) method, which clears all elements from the vector, or you can also use the [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) method, which can erase a single element or multiple.

The same rules apply with `clear` and `erase`; if the underlying type is a pointer type that has claimed memory, you need to be sure you `delete` the elements in the vector; example:

```
template < typename IteratorType >
void delete_elements(IteratorType start, IteratorType end)
{
    while (start != end) {
        delete (*start); // or delete[]
        ++start;
    }
}

std::vector<int*> v1;
v1.push_back(new int(42));
v1.push_back(new int(24));
v1.push_back(new int(38));

delete_elements(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

And if you want to see this assignment in action, you can use a little test class like the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define outi(v) std::cout << v << ", i = " << i << std::endl

class tester {
    public:
        tester() : i(42) { outi("default ctor"); }
        tester(int x) : i(x) { outi("implicit ctor"); }
        ~tester() { outi("dtor"); }
        tester(const tester& cp) : i(cp.i) { outi("copy ctor"); }
        tester& operator=(const tester& cp) {
            this->i = cp.i;
            outi("operator=");
            return *this;
        }
        // for std::cout << tester;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const tester& t) {
            o << t.i; return o;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

template < typename itr >
static void printall(itr start, itr end)
{
    while (start != end) {
        std::cout << (*start) << std::endl;
        ++start;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<tester> v1;
    std::cout << "create v1 elements" << std::endl;
    v1.push_back(10); // implicit ctor calls
    v1.push_back(24);
    v1.push_back(33);
    printall(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::vector<tester> v2;
    std::cout << "create v2 elements" << std::endl;
    v2.push_back(tester(100));
    v2.push_back(tester(99));
    printall(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    std::cout << "v1 = v2" << std::endl;
    //v1.clear(); // uncomment to call dtor's
    v1 = v2;
    printall(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Where the output of this program might be something like the following:

```
create v1 elements
implicit ctor, i = 10
copy ctor, i = 10
dtor, i = 10
implicit ctor, i = 24
copy ctor, i = 10
dtor, i = 10
copy ctor, i = 24
dtor, i = 24
implicit ctor, i = 33
copy ctor, i = 10
copy ctor, i = 24
dtor, i = 10
dtor, i = 24
copy ctor, i = 33
dtor, i = 33
10
24
33
create v2 elements
implicit ctor, i = 100
copy ctor, i = 100
dtor, i = 100
implicit ctor, i = 99
copy ctor, i = 100
dtor, i = 100
copy ctor, i = 99
dtor, i = 99
100
99
v1 = v2
operator=, i = 100
operator=, i = 99
dtor, i = 33
100
99
dtor, i = 100
dtor, i = 99
dtor, i = 100
dtor, i = 99
```

I say *might* because your compiler could choose to order the constructors/assignment slightly different, but the results will be the same.

I hope that can help.

Answer (score 2):

The old values of `v1` are destroyed when `v1` is assigned to, because the assignment removes the earlier content.

To clear a vector immediately without assigning a new value, you can use the `clear` method or the `resize` method.

Comment: note: the old vector entries probably are not *destructed*  (instead, assignment operator is used to change the values). Not sure if you were intentionally making a distinction between *destructed* and *destroyed* (and if so, whether OP understands that)

Comment: @M.M. It's not the best answer. Before the edit window was gone I realized that I'd answered something totally meaningless, misreading the question's code totally. Then when I added the second paragraph I discovered I'd added it to Joachin Pileborg's (now deleted) answer instead of my own. This was before coffee.